# Problems Enumerated Deque<Double>()

Tags: deque, swift4.2, xcode11.4

I use "attaswift/Deque" library. I have a double Deque;

```
var pointsZ =  Deque<Double>()
```

I want to use;

```
for (index,value) in pointsZ.enumerated(){
...
}
```

I got error "For-in loop requires `EnumeratedSequence<Deque<Double>>` to conform to `Sequence`" in Xcode 11.4.1. How can solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you need to provide more information so people can help you. Where is `Deque` coming from? What's its definition and the definition of `enumerated`? Etc. Edit your question to add these details and someone will undoubtedly help you.

Comment: @CRD thanks for your useful comment. I edited my question. I solve my problem using the other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my for loop like;

```
for i in 0..<pointsZ.count {
               print(pointsZ[i])
 }
```

It solve my problem.